# BlackBerry audio playback from SDCard file

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I've started working on audio playback by looking at the code in the support forum article "[Streaming media - Start to finish](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Streaming-media-Start-to-finish/ta-p/488255)"

If you take a look at OptionsScreen.java, you'll notice "MenuItem localSD = new MenuItem("Use SDCard/media/", 1, 1)", which suggest the app is also able to play medias stored in the SD card. I modified that part a bit into this:

```
MenuItem localSD = new MenuItem("Use SDCard/media/", 1, 1){
    public void run(){
        if(urlField.getText().indexOf("file://")==-1){
            String url = urlField.getText();
            urlField.setText("file:///SDCard/media/05 - Firth Of Fifth.mp3");
        }
    }
};
```

Yes, I have "use PC file system for SD cards" enabled in the simulator. The media directory is already in the "SD card directory", and also the MP3. Strangely, the MP3 doesn't play at all. But if you try to stream from web server, as pointer by "MenuItem audio1 = new MenuItem("Audio1 (MP3)", 1, 1)", then no problem at all. The audio plays.

How to fix this, then?

Comment: I don't understand ... what's the problem?  Writing a seek bar UI?  Adding a `MenuItem`?  The URL `file:///SDCard/media/05 - Firth Of Fifth.mp3` doesn't play?  Have you tried a URL without spaces in it?  Which device/simulator are you using?

Comment: Actually what I'm asking about is how to make the sample app play audios which is stored in the micro SD. BTW, files without spaces on their names don't work either. Maybe if you run the code on simulator you'll understand what I'm talking about. I did the testing on Curve 8520 simulator :)

Comment: You should probably **edit** your title, because right now, it doesn't describe your actual problem.  Which OS version is your 8520 simulator?

Comment: RIM streaming samples are very buggy.